# Javascript string.slice() with negative values

Tags: javascript, html, bigcommerce

I am trying to hide or show divs based on the title of the page.  This is only required because I can't figure out a better way of passing a value into the page.

Here's the current code in the HTML file:

```
function toggle(divId) {
    var divArray = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(i = 0; i < divArray.length; i++){
        if(divArray[i].id == divId){
            if(divArray[i].style.display != 'none'){
                divArray[i].style.display = 'none';
            }else{
                divArray[i].style.display = '';
            }
        }
    }
}

    function togglePayLink() {
    var h1Array = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    for(i = 0; i < h1Array.length; i++){
        if(h1Array[i].id == 'Title'){
            var title = h1Array[i].innerHTML;
            title = title.slice(1);
            title = title.slice(-4);
            toggle('descr'+ title);
        }
    }
}
```

Also in the HTML file is a header with the page title.  The %%GLOBAL_PageTitle%% is replaced in server side code that I don't have access to.  However, the values will be "$100 Fee" (with different numbers).

```
<h1 id="Title" class="TitleHeading">%%GLOBAL_PageTitle%%</h1>
```

Finally, I have a set of hidden divs with id's in the format descr + a number, so if the page title is "$100 Fee" I want to show the div with the id "descr100".

```
<div id="descr100" style="display:none;width: 75%;"></div>
```

When the script above runs, I get no error (I'm using chrome's console), but the div does not show.  I know the toggle function works because it was previously being used with only a single div on the page that had to be toggled.  I wrote the togglePayLink function, which I assume is the issue, but I have no idea how to debug this.  I was wondering if the dollar sign in the title could be causing issues, but I would think I would get an error if that were the case.

EDIT: Changed the togglePayLink function to use var instead of string, but I'm getting a typeError when slice() is called.

Comment: This might help clean up your script, but you can take a look at the .hide()/.show() functions in jquery (http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and the pseudo selector .contains (https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: You don't need to loop to find elements with a particular ID. You can find them directly using `getElementById`.

Comment: It's very unlikely that the line `String title = h1Array[i].innerHTML;` would not generate a syntax error--what console are you looking at? Anyway, you should step through your code line by line using the debugger, examining variables at each point. Finally, manipulating style properties directly as you are doing is generally less preferable than toggling a class, which you can do with `elt.classList.toggle('hide')` or something similar. Also, slicing at hard-wired points in the string is fragile; consider using something like `title.match(\/d+/)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

title.slice(-4) was giving me the last four digits of the string instead of everything before the last four digits like I thought it would.  toggling the non-existent 'descrFee' div was not doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Going forward, you should probably just assign a unique class to the page using %%GLOBAL_PageTitle%%. This way you can show/hide elements using CSS.

```
<div class="page %%GLOBAL_PageTitle%%">
```

For pages that BigCommerce doesn't give access to the HTML of the h1 for each individual page (ex. Web Pages, Account, Cart), I usually run this script on page load to strip the page title of spaces and other characters, and assign a specific class to the page element.

```
var catName = $('.TitleHeading').text();
var catName = catName.replace(/ /g, '');         
var catName = catName.replace(/'/g, '');
var catName = catName.replace(/&/g, '');
var catName = $.trim(catName);
$('.page').addClass(''+catName+'');
```

The way your doing it seems a bit over the top, but if it was setup this way by someone else, I understand.

Comment: If I use css, isn't the element shown static?  I can't have any of the divs showing on page load.

Comment: I would hide all the divs and only show the ones you'd like via CSS when the page has that certain class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
String title = h1Array[i].innerHTML;
```

In Javascript, all variables are set with var (except for functions, which can be set other ways). So it would be:

```
var title = h1Array[i].innerHTML;
```

Additionally, you probably have to define it outside the for loop, in which case you would omit the "var" when you are setting it in the for loop:

```
<script language="javascript">
    var title;
    function togglePayLink() {
        var h1Array = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
        for(i = 0; i < h1Array.length; i++){
            if(h1Array[i].id == 'Title'){
                title = h1Array[i].innerHTML;
                title = title.slice(1);
                title = title.slice(-4);
                toggle('descr'+ title);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Edit: If you only use it in the for loop, but use it in different iterations, then I'm not sure if it can be defined locally. I'd still define it globally, though.

Comment: Why would you loop over all `h1` tags to find one with a particular ID when you could simply address it directly using `getElementById`?

Comment: *Additionally, you probably have to define it outside the for loop* Why?

Comment: @torazaburo I simply left it the way he had programmed it. I defined it outside the loop in case he needed to use it later.

Comment: *I defined it outside the loop in case he needed to use it later.* Please read up on JS variable scope.

Comment: @torazaburo Oh, for loops don't create their own scope? Makes sense, I guess.... Thanks.    : )

Comment: It was var originally, I decided to try string before posting and forgot to change it back.  Changing it back to var has had no effect.

Comment: Changing it to var title = h1Array[i].html; gives a TypeError when slice() is called.  Is there a reason that the html could return as something other than a string?

Comment: @dragoncmd I don't know, but you could always manually convert it to a string. You could also try the "new String()" constructor function.

Comment: @Feathercrown, indeed, JavaScript doesn't have block scope (unless you use `let`). So, in the following code: `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){ for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){ console.log(i); } }`, you may think that it will log something 20 times, but it will not: this is an infinite loop, because `var i` in the outer loop is the same `var i` in the inner loop.